# Able to connect to server via ssh but not via sftp (bash -> zsh)

Tags: bash, ssh, bashrc, sftp, zsh

OS: Ubuntu 20.04

Hello everyone,

I am able to connect to a remote machine via my terminal:

```bash
ssh remote_name
```

Nonetheless I cannot connect via sftp (thus not able to use Nautilus to access my remote files).

```bash
sftp remote_name
```

The remote name is stored in my `.ssh/config` file like this:

```bash
Host remote_name
        HostName remote_adress
        User user_name
```

The authentification is done via a keyfile: my `.ssh/id_rsa.pub` key is stored in my remote machine at `.ssh/authorized_keys`.

[EDIT] I realized the issue appeared after I tried to change my "default" shell on my remote machine. Unfortunately, this is a shared server so I cannot set my default shell using `chsh`... So I'm just calling `zsh` at the end of my `.bashrc`.

That is the cause of my problme as suggested by this post: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/364574

I would like to keep using zsh on my remote machine, do you have any suggestion to make `sftp` connection work ?

Thanks for your help !

Paul

Comment: Please [edit] your question and tell us how you authenticate to the remote server. Password? Keyfile? Something else? Is that set in your `~/.ssh/config`? Can you show us the relevant lines (change IPs or other sensitive information but make sure they are consistent so we can understand)?

Comment: thanks for your suggestions @terdon, I edited my original post. Let me know is you need anything else :)

Answer (score 1):

A friend of mine suggested me a solution:

In my remote `.bashrc`, instead of direclty calling `zsh` at the end, I restrict the call to zsh with this condition:

```bash
if [ "$SSH_TTY" ]
then
   zsh
fi
```

Now I can ssh (and I have zsh as my remote terminal), and sftp connection works too !

Hope this will help others :)